# convert negative to the positive if there is a string

Tags: python, math, module

```py
lst = [1, 'Some Text', 50, 2, -54, 2.0, 'Python', 47, -10, 34, -1, -3, 7, 'Code']
```

Create a function that iterates over the list and checks if there is a negative value and converts it to a positive value with the help of the `math` module. Finally, you just need to print a list.

Answer (score 1):

```
[abs(num) if not isinstance(num, str) else num for num in lst]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
l=[]
for i in lst:
    if isinstance(i, int):
        l.append(abs(i))
    else:
        l.append(i)
```

This should work fine

Comment: Your code will fail to provide the correct result if -3.4 is in the list.

Comment: [abs(num) if not isinstance(num, str) else num for num in lst]  This should work fine for float too.